# Do "small" and "large" numbers actually exist in an absolute sense?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, big-numbers

Numbers like $(10)^{-10^{10^{10}}}$  are generally regarded as small, whereas numbers like, for example, Graham's Number, are regarded as extremely large. My question is, are these numbers simply "small" and "large" *relative* to "every day" numbers or are the notions of "smallness" and "largeness" absolute in some sense, meaning that "small" and "large" numbers can be objectively categorized in a meaningful mathematical way.

If the answer to this is, as I am presuming, no, that it is simply relative, then is it also true that the words "small" and "large" have no relevance in pure mathematics, where "every day" numbers are generally not privileged? What significance exactly do the symbols $>>$ and $<<$ have in pure mathematics? Or sayings like "for small $n$" or "for large $n$"?

Comment: Like you have said, smallness of a number is up to a relative sense, not necessarily to "every day" numbers though. We are interested in "sufficiently small (large)" numbers in many occasions, especially in analysis, which also makes a comparison with a certain number.

Comment: When we say "for large $n$', it can mean:
- that the property is true for $n$ large enough (e.g. $\forall n\geq1247$)
- that the property is true asymptotically (but not for any fixed $n$).

Comment: One single grain doesn't make a pile of sand, two don't neither, but 10000000000 grains surely do. But how many grains will count as the "critical point"? Nobody can answer. Because the way people define "a pile of sand" is subjective.

Comment: However, you may sometimes encounter things like "for $n$ large enough"  "for $\delta$ small enough" etc. in describing a **limit**. Well, that's just an informal definition of the limit, the formal version is $$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists N\in\Bbb N\,(\text{or}\,\exists\delta>0)\,\text{s.t. something related to}\,n\,(\text{or}\,\delta)<\epsilon\,\text{as long as}\,n>N\,(\text{or}\,|x-x_0|<\delta)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbols $\gg$ and $\ll$ don't have a formal definition. Usually they are used to compare two extremely big numbers, for example $\mathrm{Graham's \; number} \ll \mathrm{TREE}(3)$ or something like that. They are only used because someone wants to make clear that one of them is so much greater.

The numbers are indeed just small compared to everyday standards. Because when you compare $10^{-10^{10^{10}}}$ and $10^{-\mathrm{Graham's \; number}}$, you can see that $10^{-10^{10^{10}}}$ is actually much larger.

The saying [$P(n)$ for small $n$], where $P(n)$ is a proposition, formally means that there exists a $\varepsilon > 0$ such that for all $0<n<\varepsilon$ we have that $P(n)$ is true.

Similiar, the saying [$P(n)$ for large $n$], where $P(n)$ is a proposition, formally means that there exists a $M > 0$ such that for all $n>M$ we have that $P(n)$ is true.

Comment: Actually, in number theory usually $\ll$ stands for the [Vinogradov symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#History_.28Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau.2C_Hardy.2C_and_Vinogradov_notations.29). Basically a notation like $f(x) \ll_{\epsilon} g(x)$ means: there is a constant $C > 0$ depending only on $\epsilon$ such that $f(x) < C g(x)$. I've never seen it used to compare numbers, though.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding everyday perception of number and the question of what "large" ought to mean, there is the field of [Numerical cognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_cognition) with many interesting experiments. E.g. when you flash a sheet with some dots for a second, people will be able to tell if there is only one dot, or two, or three. If there are three dots, people who see it for one second will not fail to claim the right number of dots that were on the sheet. "3!" But past about 7 dots people they suddenly get very bad at this game. Futher up, humans have no way or distinguishing $10^5$ form $10^6$ dots at all.